# Order by with repeat sequence sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks somewhat like this:

```
Points      Sequence
----------  --------
100,001.00  0
100,002.00  0
100,003.00  0
100,004.00  0
100,005.00  1
100,006.00  1
100,007.00  1
100,008.00  1
100,009.00  2
100,010.00  2
100,011.00  2
100,012.00  2
```

Is there any way we can achieve following output using order by.

```
Points      Sequence
----------  --------
100,001.00  0
100,005.00  1
100,009.00  2
100,002.00  0
100,006.00  1
100,010.00  2
100,003.00  0
100,008.00  1
100,011.00  2
100,004.00  0
100,007.00  1
100,012.00  2
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to interleave the rows, so rows with the same `sequence` are *separated* rather than being adjacent in the result set.

You can use `row_number()` in an `order by` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by sequence order by points),
         sequence;
```